# How to check if i am in a transaction?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sqlite, ado.net, transactions

I have a piece of code i recently expanded but now must use a transaction. It looks like it can only be access while in a transaction but looks like doesnt make me feel comfortable. Using SQLite and ADO.NET i wrote `if(cmd.Transaction==null)` but it is null and in a transaction. How should i check?

NOTE: I will be using this code with TSQL in the future. This is a quick prototype with SQLite

-edit- i was thinking of nesting transactions but this code generates a piece of sql and uses a command to add parameters too. So adding a nested transaction would take a lot of modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the nature of the SQL and its fit in the application, it may be more appropriate for you to nest transactions, ensuring a transaction is present regardless of the context of the call.

For example, you could wrap the calling code in a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) block. If there is a transaction present, this will have no real effect on the operation. If there is no transaction present, it will create a transaction and ensure the ADO.NET code participates in the transaction.

This approach only works if you're happy for the SQL to be executed as a single operation. If it should only be called as part of a larger transaction, this approach doesn't help.

To know for sure that a transaction is present, you have to check for the explicit transaction on the ADO.NET command (as you have above) and also the presence of an ambient transaction from the `System.Transactions` programming model using the [`Transaction.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current.aspx) property.

Comment: I dont see a Transaction.Current but i can write `cmd.Transaction = tns;`

Comment: The Transaction class is in System.Transactions namespace, which is found in the System.Transactions assembly.